# Перегрузить оператор сдвига вправо

Tags: c++

Компилятор говорит что слишком много параметров для этой функции оператора. Но когда я выношу за пределы класса все работает
Подскажите что можно сделать так чтобы перегрузка оператора была в классе и все работало

```
class String
    {
        char* str;
        int n = 50;
    
    public:
    void operator << (String& src, int num)
        {
            char* tmp = new char[src.n];
            memset(tmp, 0, src.n);
            memcpy(tmp, &src.str[num], src.n - num);
            memcpy(src.str, tmp, src.n);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Примерно так ```String& operator << (int num)```

Comment: Если вы сделаете ее свободной функцией — нормально. Как член класса, она неявно получает еще `*this`. Получается тернарный оператор...